# Phonegap: image upload >65k

Tags: android, file-upload, cordova

I'm developing an phonegap under android and I want to upload pictures to a server.

The thing is, that the user can choose pictures from the gallery or he can take pictures from the camera. Every pictures is shown as a thumbnail in a list. After the user has decided which pictures he wants, he can upload the pictures by pressing a button.

When I choose pictures from the gallery which are smaler than 65k everything works fine, but when I tried it with bigger pictures I get a http 400 error - bad request.

The max requestlength of the webservice is set to 100m, so does anybody know how I can increase the limit? 1 or 2 Mb would be enough.

Here´s some of my code -> get the file I want to upload:

```
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(rootFS.fullPath + "/Folder/Picturename.jpg", onGetPic, onFail);
```

And than upload the recieved entry

```
function onGetPic(entry)
{
var options = new FileUploadOptions();
options.fileKey = "file";
var imagefilename = entry.name;
options.fileName = imagefilename;
options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";
options.chunkedMode = false;

var params = new Object();
params.RefType = iRefType;
params.RefID = iRefID;

options.params = params;

var ft = new FileTransfer();
ft.upload(entry.fullPath, window.localStorage["url"] + "WebService.svc/UploadPhoto", onSuccess, onFail, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. It was the problem of the web.config. I configured the maximum upload size at the wrong section. Here is want I changed:

```
<webHttpBinding>
<binding    
  maxBufferPoolSize="2147483647" 
  maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647" 
  maxBufferSize="2147483647" transferMode="Streamed">
<security mode="Transport" />
</binding>
```

Comment: Hi, this question has been 2 years but i am wondering where is the web.config file? I have been facing an error_code 1 for my upload script. when i do ft.upload